# cursor with a following div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that follows the cursor around the screen.
How can I tell the script to act like that only in a specific area of the page?

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
$('.galleria-counter').css({
left:  e.pageX,
top:   e.pageY
});
});
```

JSFIDDLE — https://jsfiddle.net/83k4ahdm/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mind me posting another answer of what I would consider most 'correct' :

```
$('#here').hover(function() {

  $(this).on('mousemove', function(e) {

    $('.galleria-counter').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
    });
  });

},
function() {

  $(this).off('mousemove'); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83k4ahdm/5/

Comment: thanks, it works fine. I didn't know though that the follower div would have remained there inside the div in a pretty much random position, and I don't like that thing at all :)

Comment: It's jQuery so you can place it anywhere you like, fade it in and out or flip it upside down. :-)

Answer (score 0):

bind your script to only div instead of document

```
 $('#here').bind('mousemove', function(e){
$('.galleria-counter').css({
left:  e.pageX,
top:   e.pageY
});
});
```

updated fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83k4ahdm/3/)

Comment: if you want cursor only for div then remove following css :
html{
cursor: url(http://www.thisisfed.com/img/extra/plus.cur), auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

First, try not to use left and top properties when you want to move something and prefere translate:transform

Second, you can delimited your call by trying something like this:

```
if( e.pageX >= div.offset().left && 
    e.pageX <= div.offset().left + div.width || 
    e.pageY >= div.offset().top && 
    e.pageY <= div.offset().top + div.height ) {
  $('.galleria-counter').css({
    left:  e.pageX,
    top:   e.pageY
  });
}
```

Hope it's help :)

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. `$('#here').on('mousemove'` will only fire over the div anyway.

Comment: Yes you are right, i didn't think  doing this way.. but my first advice is still correct.
But with this way to do so, you don't need a div to delimited the area.. (I'm trying to argue my point :p )

Comment: I was on the `offset()` road as well so can relate to that. :-D